# Prevent Joomla to add slashes when save a template

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I feel so dumb to ask this question... but... When I try to edit (with joomla template manager, joomla 3.0) a template that contain php code, when I save it joomla add slashes and so my php crash and the page is not visible anymore... How can I fix that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

You are experiencing this issues because you have Magic Quotes GPC turned on for your account or at least for the folder your Joomla 3.0 resides in. As mentioned in the post, it needs to be turned off and this is now a strict requirement for the Joomla application to work properly. I’d advise you to revert the changes you’ve made to the core Joomla files and simply disable Magic Quotes GPC. To do that, you can use the PHP Variables Manager tool in your cPanel(http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_change_the_value_of_a_PHP_setting.html).